# Nginx SSL redirect from internal location

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am doing pretty nasty things with nginx. Here is the birds-eye view.

nginx plays the role of a proxy between myriads of S3 buckets. In order to determine the correct bucket, I use Lua scripts on top of OpenResty platform.

So, firstly request enters `/` location and got processed by the Lua script.

```
location / {
  listen 8001;
  server_name $hostname;
  access_by_lua_file '/srv/hostingrouter/live/hostingrouter/storerouter.lua';
  proxy_pass http://$remote;
}

location ~ /s3/(?<s3_key>.+) {
  internal;
  proxy_pass $s3;
  rewrite .* /$s3_key break;
}
```

I cannot show you full Lua script because of NDA(hope you killaz understand me), but it does the next call somewhere between conditions:

```lua
return ngx.exec(
  '/s3/' .. s3_key
)
```

The tricky part is that Lua script does some other redirects too. But only in that particular case that showed above, I need to rewrite URL from HTTP to HTTPS.

I believe `rewrite http:// https:// break;` wouldn't work because matched path doesn't have scheme(I also tried it and it didn't work). Moreover, I tried to do a conditional redirect:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

but it resulted in a loop redirect.

How to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS from internal location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is to make an `ngx.redirect` BEFORE the `ngx.exec`(i.e. in the Lua file). No need for special processing inside `nginx.conf`.